# How to set parent entity Id when posting/creating child entity object with web api

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have two Entity-Framework entities (A child "Note", which belongs to a Folder) and scaffolded web api's for each. I can create Folders and want to be able to add notes to those folders.

```
public class Note
    {
        public int Id {get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50), Required]
        public string NoteTitle { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1000), Required]
        public string NoteContent { get; set; }
        
        public NoteFolder NoteFolder { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class NoteFolder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FolderName { get; set; }

    }
```

My POST:

```
let Note = {
                "NoteTitle": this.NoteTitle(),
                "NoteContent": this.NoteContent(),
                "NoteFolder_Id:": ParentFolderId 
                };

            
            $.ajax({
                url: `http://localhost:52657/api/Notes`,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location.replace("http://localhost:52657/");
                    alert(`Successfully Created New Note: ${Note.NoteTitle}`)
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(Note)
            });
```

Endpoint:

```
 // POST: api/Notes
        [ResponseType(typeof(Note))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostNote(Note note)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Notes.Add(note);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = note.Id }, note);
        }
```

Whenever I make a post request, the note is created but the foreign key row NoteFolder_Id is null in my database. How do fix this?

Edit: I've tried posting:

```
"NoteFolder": { "Id": ParentFolderId }
```

so that it can be serialized properly, however this resulted in a new Folder being created in the db, with an auto incremented Id, and the created Note making reference to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Note class and performing migrations,

```
 public class Note
    {
        public int Id {get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50), Required]
        public string NoteTitle { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1000), Required]
        public string NoteContent { get; set; }

        public int? FolderId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FolderId")]
        public NoteFolder NoteFolder { get; set; }
    }
```

then sending the post in the form:

```
let Note = {
                "NoteTitle": this.NoteTitle(),
                "NoteContent": this.NoteContent(),
                "FolderId": ParentFolderId 
                };
```

fixed the issue.

Still unsure why passing a NoteFolder object resulted in a new folder being created in the db. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx this site uses my initial model style to map 1:n.